# Query only records that fall within a date range with postgresSQL (Redshift)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to grab all records from today's date to 14 weeks prior. I also need that same week but a year ago. I have the following:

```
WHERE date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-14, current_date))
OR date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-52, current_date))
OR date(date) <= date(dateadd(week,-53, current_date))
```

It doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working properly" mean? Do you get an error message? Get the wrong rows? PostgreSQL doesn't natively support nonstandard date functions like `dateadd()`. Does Redshift? What does "that same week but a year ago" mean? Same calendar days, same week number during the year, same ISO week, something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the use of `INTERVAL` to subtract from `GETDATE()` -- it may make things easier to read/reason about, but `DATEADD` should work in theory (although it isn't standard *Postgres* -- `INTERVAL` is).

One thing that immediately stands out from your stated requirements versus your code is that as written, from a boolean-logic perspective, the code doesn't match your requirements.

You said you need all records from between today and 14 weeks ago, **and** also from the same week a year ago.

What your code says is: give me all records where the date is within the past 14 weeks, **or** the date is greater than 52 weeks ago **or** the date is less than 53 weeks ago.

From a purely boolean perspective, what you want is more like something like this:

```
WHERE date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-14, current_date))
   OR (date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-52, current_date))
       AND date(date) <= date(dateadd(week,-53, current_date))
      )
```

Note the additional set of parenthesis, and the switch amongst the additional set from `or` to `and`.

Additionally, I think you also may want to, within that additional set of parens, reverse the `>=` and `<=`, since in this case it's the larger negative number that represents the *earlier* date. This will all depend on exactly how `DATEADD` works, which I'm not familiar with since I use *Postgres* instead of *Redshift* (*Redshift* is a fork of *Postgres 8.0*), but based on how [the Redshift doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) seems to say it works, I believe you do want them reversed.

So then it becomes:

```
WHERE date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-14, current_date))
   OR (date(date) <= date(dateadd(week,-52, current_date))
       AND date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-53, current_date))
      )
```

This is what I meant by it might be easier to reason about the logic when using `INTERVAL` -- using these large negative offsets, while they can certainly be made to work, just aren't as intuitive to reason about, IMO. It may also be worth switching the two sides of the inner `AND`, so the `-53`, the earlier value, is on the left side (won't change the functionality, but may make the use of `DATEADD` easier to reason about within this code).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0. It doesn't support the "interval" data type, but docs say it does support interval arithmetic.  I don't see any hint that it supports `dateadd()`, but I might have missed it.

This query will work as written on current versions of PostgreSQL and on SQLFiddle for testing and verification. I don't think it will work as written on Redshift, but the important part for you is just the WHERE clause. The common table expression is just to give us a calendar to do interval arithmetic against. You won't need it on Redshift.

It's not clear what you mean by "that same week but a year ago". You don't mention any particular week; you seem to be interested in a 14-week period. This query returns rows from

- 2014-09-23 (14 weeks ago) to 2014-12-30 (current date), and
- the same dates in 2013.

  ```
  with calendar as (
   select (generate_series((current_date - interval '18 months'), current_date, '1 day'))::date cal_date
  )
  select cal_date
  from calendar
  where cal_date between (current_date - interval '14 weeks')::date 
                     and current_date
     or cal_date between ((current_date - interval '1 year')::date - interval '14 weeks')::date 
                     and (current_date - interval '1 year')::date 
  order by cal_date;
  ```

```
cal_date
--
2013-09-23
...
2013-12-30
2014-09-23
...
2014-12-30
```